# Sending APDU commands from Android device over CCID to the Gemalto PC Twin Reader

Tags: android, usb, smartcard-reader, gemalto

I'm developing an android library that communicates with smart card readers (USB) using the CCID protocol. On [this reader](https://nedis.com/en-us/product/computer/storage-memory/cardreaders/550670253/card-reader-smart-card-id-usb-20) everything works as expected, but when using the Gemalto reader, I get an error.

I'll try to describe what I'm doing:

- I send PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn command.

Request:

> 62000000000001010000

Response (ATR = `3B7E9400008025D20310010056000000020200`):

> 801300000000010000003B7E9400008025D20310010056000000020200

- TPDU for PPS exchange

Request:

> 6F040000000002010000FF1013FC

Response:

> 80040000000002000000FF1013FC

- PC_to_RDR_SetParameters

Request:

> 610500000000030100001300000A00

Response:

> 820700000000030000011310000A008000

- APDU command (`APDU Selet Applet - 00A40000023F00`)

Request:

> 6F07000000000401000000A40000023F00

Response:

> 8000000000000440FE

slot status 40h

```
An ICC is present and inactive (not activated or
shut down by hardware error)
```

I expect status word [`6D00`] in the response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest capturing card session with both readers on PC (using official drivers) and analyzing/comparing logs. This approach worked for me in the past. Wireshark has USB-CCID dissector and USB capturing is described [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB). Good luck with your project.